# OpenVPN on a campus network?

Tags: security, vpn, firewall, openvpn, tunnel

I have my router at home running Tomato USB with OpenVPN running on port 1194. The campus network only has port 80 publicly open and I'm almost positive that they do traffic shaping and content filtering. Is my only option here to change the port OpenVPN is running on in Tomato USB to port 80 and connect from the campus within the client from port 80?

Comment: You can certainly try, however, based on what you said, they probably inspect HTTP packets, which VPN traffic is NOT.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will definitely give it a try this week.

Comment: does your ISP have port 80 open tho? many ISPs block it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not making advertisement, but in my campus SwissVPN (which runs OpenVPN) works fine because those guys configured the OpenVPN server to accept connections on port 443 (often used for HTTPS) and since the OpenVPN socket is SSL layered, to the stupid firewall in my campus it's like I'm doing HTTPS with some server.

HTTPS is not *trivially* distinguishable from anything else running on an SSL socket. Some poor firewalls assume SSL on 443 == HTTPS.

Try it out (setting your own VPN server on port 443 or try SwissVPN free test), it might work.

If it doesn't work and you have much spare time, you can try to find some HTTP tunneling tool but it's not clean as OpenVPN.

Comment: Thanks, but port 443 isn't open on my campus.

Comment: @Aaron Port 443 isn't open? What do they do when users need to access HTTPS sites??

Comment: Outgoing traffic for port 443 is allowed (we can definitely access https sites), but if you ran a port scan against the network (so someone from the outside trying to access the campus network), port 443 is closed. Actually, that makes me want to try to see if they allow outbound traffic on port 1194 or port 80. Guess I will give it a try sometime this week...Also, I thought you don't need port 443 open to access https sites? If I wasn't running OpenVPN, every single other port at my home router is closed (from an external standpoint)...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answers, or you're messing up with the concept of 'open ports'.
It's obvious that you can't accept inbound connections from inside your campus network without a tunnel, to any port of yours. But you can establish outbound connections, to *some* ports of other servers on the Internet. It's not your 443 port being open, it's just: "outbound connections to port 443 of OTHER hosts are allowed". It's different!
More, if your home router doesn't accept inbound connections, then the problem has NO solution unless you use a third node.

Comment: @Aaron - you need port 443 open outbound to access https websites. Running a scan against the network only checks for inbound ports. (I know - huge simplification:-) The two are entirely distinct!

Comment: @Rory: To be more precise... All of your local ports are open outbound, because otherwise nothing would work. I explain. To access https websites you have to be behind a NAT that allows outbound connections **TO** port 443 of some host. The local port is different. When you run HTTPS, the remote port is 443, the local one can be any free one < 1024 (on many systems), so it can be 5564, 6675, 2223, who knows, etc...

Comment: I meant > 1024 :P

Comment: @Giacomo - (yeah I know, hence my simplification comment :-) Just trying to separate the concepts to help Aaron's thinking.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Port 80 (incoming) is open on my campus' network, but not to my machine. At home, only the port for OpenVPN is open, so that is all set. It works fine from other places. I tried connecting to my router at home this week from the campus and it did not work, so I guess I will just go the route of setting up an SSH tunnel. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Aaron, why don't you put OpenVPN at home on port 443, so that your campus network will be easily eluded (since OpenVPN on 443 is indistinguishable from HTTPS), like we're telling you from the beginning. Have a try, please, I guess it works just fine. I still think you're making a bit of confusion, instead it's quite simple: your campus network will most likely allow you outgoing connections to ports 80 and 443 of other servers (maybe also POP3 and SMTP). Please keep in mind (or learn) what ports actually mean.

Comment: I will give it a try, but I was under the impression that openvpn needs more than just an outgoing connection on whatever port I use. I thought you need inbound and outbound access. Am I wrong?

Comment: As a server, you need inbound access. As a client, you need to perform an outgoing connection to a certain port of a properly configured OpenVPN server. It's a classic client-server design. If this port is 443, OpenVPN can mimic HTTPS, being almost undetectable by many corporate firewalls. Some other firewalls are more clever and will break the pipe between client and server, basing on the fact that "no HTTPS connection is sometimes idle for 10 minutes!", so you'll have to reconnect every n minutes or go for a different solution (I had fair results with HTTP 'segmented' tunneling - slow)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I forgot to mark this answer as the best answer. I also wanted to let everyone know that I just had to change the port OpenVPN was using to 443. After doing that, everything worked fine.

Comment: Glad to hear. SSL on port 443 is the main flaw of every corporate firewall (as of outgoing connections)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to run WinSSHD on my pc on campus  (on port 80 rather than 22)  and then open a tunnel from the outside using Tunnelier client.  Then, map ports as needed to tunnel through.   This isn't a VPN and so you have to manually map ports... things aren't wide open like on a VPN connection.    Just an idea in case your VPN method doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I was actually able to get OpenVPN up and running. The main issue was that my school blocks so many outgoing ports, and one of them happened to be 1194. Changing the server on the router to listen on port 443 and connecting via port 443 did the trick.

Comment: You aren't connecting via port 443, you're probably using a random port... The server listens on 443 :)

Comment: Quick question. Let's say I am connecting to an SSH server on some server that's running it on port 22. When I try connecting to an SSH server running on my VPS or even when trying to connect to Github (from the campus), it's blocked. Now, what I have done is change my VPS's SSH server to listen on a completely different port which allows me to connect from campus. If I am connecting to that different port on my VPS but am most likely using a random port on my machine on campus for the outbound connection, what would be stopping all outbound connections to port 22? Can firewalls prevent that?

Comment: Most networks are configured to allow outgoing ports.  For example, web browsers use the 3000 range for returning connections. It is possible though that firewalls can block traffic based on protocol type rather than by port.